# How to compare 2 regression models?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, standard-deviation, standard-error

Suppose I have 2 regerssion models `A` and `B`, and dataset for evaluation containing `N` samples, for each sample I can estimate MAE(mean absolute error), then I can compute average MAE across dataset and compute standard error, so I have something like:

For model A: `avr_mae1 +- standard_error1`

For model B: `avr_mae2 +- standard_error2`

For now I'm just comparing `avr_mae1` vs `avr_mae2` to understand which model is better, but intuitively I understand that model with low `avr_mae` and large `standard_error` is not very usefull model, so what is the proper way of comparing models, some statistical test?

My second question is: my model come from deep neural network and training process is not fully deterministic, so I can have slightly different results from run to run, so my question: is it true that if intervals `avr_mae1 + standard_error1` and `avr_mae2 - standard_error2` cross I can say that models are have about the same performance?

Comment: How are you computing an average MAE and a standard error for it? Is this the whole model MAE?

Comment: @user2974951 For each sample in dataset I have ground truth value and predicted value, so I can compute MAE for single sample, then I average across samples to obtain average MAE.

Comment: I don't understand. How many data sets / samples do you have? How many testing / evaluations data sets do you have? On which data sets were the two regression models built on?

Comment: @user2974951 I have 1 evaluation dataset containing N samples.

Comment: You haven't answered my questions regarding the training data sets and models.

Comment: @user2974951 I train model A and model B on same training data if you mean that.

Comment: OK, so you train two models A and B on the same data set and get a MAE out of both? How do estimate a standard error for each model then?

Comment: @user2974951 via formula `std/sqrt(N)` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error , where std is MAE std across evaluation dataset containing N samples.

Comment: MAE represents one value, a measure of centrality for one model, so where did you get the `std` of this measure?

Comment: @user2974951 I can compute MAE for each sample in evaluation dataset, so I can compute mean and std across N samples.

Comment: OK... so you have an evaluation data set, which is completely independent of the training set? And this evaluation data set contains N samples, so basically you have N evaluation data sets? Why? Why are these samples not aggregated?